# DNS configuration set with netplan works for some hours, then stops working

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, netplan

I have a lot of VM running, all of them with the same network config, except for their IP that are fixed and range from 10.36.8.2 to 10.36.8.250. Most of them are accessed with their IP, but some are given a name for our ease. 
As such, I have 2 VM that are named `jira` and `confluence`. They used to be hosted on an ubuntu 12.04, but I recently created 2 new VM, running Xubuntu 18.04 and moved them.
To work correctly, `confluence` needs to reach `jira` by its name, and never had a problem on my 12.04.

With 18.04, I discovered `netplan` and this is my current configuration : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwn6T.png

It works fine, the machine can ping jira. But for a reason I fail to understand, the DNS config of `confluence` breaks after some hours/days, even though the machine is idle and I've disabled every update in the Software & Update window.
When it happens, pinging jira gives me

> Name or service not known

All the other machines can ping jira, so I know for fact it's the `confluence` vm that is at fault. To fix my problem, I just have to run the following command :

> sudo netplan apply

How can I fix this so I don't have to apply my netplan manually every time? Thank you

Comment: Is it just me or is that CIDR address wrong? (probably me) 10.36.8.104/21 looks like it might be a problem.

Comment: You seem sceptic, but here is the working config I've been using for 4 years https://i.imgur.com/E8ckx5i.png and here what it gives if you use a submask calculator : https://i.imgur.com/j3YZiBd.png

So it's definetely ok :)

Comment: You list three nameservers in your config, two with private IPs and one with a public IP.  Do all three of these servers know the name confluence.YOURDOMAIN?  You should not list multiple nameservers in your netplan config that do not all have the same DNS namespace view; if one of the nameservers becomes unavailable at any point and stops responding, systemd-resolved will switch to preferring the next server in the list.  So if it asks 194.2.0.20 for `confluence` and gets told NXDOMAIN, it will consider that authoritative and not fall back to the other servers.

Comment: @slangasek but then why would the problem not appear before, and in that case why would a "sudo netplan apply" fix the problem?

Comment: Prior to Ubuntu 18.04, `resolved` was not used for dns resolution.  "netplan apply" fixes it because it resets `resolved`s view of failed DNS servers.  Did you try removing the public DNS server from your config?

Comment: Your netplan yaml file suggests that Network Manager do all networking tasks but then you've populated netplan and it doesn't work as expected. I recommend that you revert the changes to netplan and set your IP and DNS in Network Manager.

Comment: @slangasek I did it this morning, will see if the problem happens again.

Comment: @chili555 I used the network manager at first and had the same problem

Comment: @slangasek I removed the "194" DNS and didn't have a problem since last week. With your explaination of how it works, I'm keen to believe that it was indeed a faulty DNS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You list three nameservers in your config, two with private IPs and one with a public IP. You should not list multiple nameservers in your netplan config that do not all have the same DNS namespace view; if one of the nameservers becomes unavailable at any point and stops responding, systemd-resolved will switch to preferring the next server in the list. So if it asks 194.2.0.20 for confluence and gets told NXDOMAIN, it will consider that authoritative and not fall back to the other servers.

The solution here is to only list the two private nameservers in the netplan config and not the public one which does not know about your internal hostnames, because they cannot be used as equivalents for failover.